# My template reference variable .nativeElement is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

this.child02.nativeElement is undefined and I can't figure out why.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you. Here is my [current stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-horizontalscrollsetup-logging2)

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component,ElementRef,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

switchDirection = true;
head: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('child02') child02: ElementRef;

  onScroll(event: Event) {
    console.log("viewBoundaryL:" + (event.target as HTMLElement).scrollLeft);
    if((event.target as HTMLElement).scrollLeft >= 50 && this.switchDirection === true){
  console.log("nativeElement:" + this.child02.nativeElement)
  console.log(this.child02)
  console.log('snap')
this.child02.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  this.switchDirection = false;
    }
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
Keep an eye on the console while scrolling...
<div class="container"  (scroll)="onScroll($event)" >

<child1></child1>
<child2 #child02></child2>
<child3></child3>

</div>
```

Context:
I am trying to make a snap-to-component-directive, similar to [this functionality (open in firefox).](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/) Here is my [current stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-horizontalscrollsetup-logging2)
My question is how would you build this?  Trying not to use a singleton.

There are so many ways to do this but heres one: When the user scrolls horizontally from one component to another component so that it comes into view fifty pixels or more past the child component boundary, the component will scrollIntoView().  Would need a switchDirection variable so that once the snap happens its not operating on the same positioning logic. And again I want to put this into directive(s).

Pseudocode for the above logic used for snapping between child 1 and child2 (see stackblitz console for context):

```
//snap from child1 to child2
    If (viewBoundary >= child1L + 50px && switchDirection === true){
child2.scrollIntoView();
switchDirection = false;
debounceTime(250);
}
//snap from child2 to child1
else if(viewBoundary <= child1R - 50px && switchDirection === false){
child1.scrollIntoView();
switchDirection = true;
debounceTime(250);
}
```

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the element using `el` like below. This is due to the fact that you have defined `#child02` on the custom component which is not a native element and hence you need to access it via `el`.

```
this.child02.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

I have verified and there are no more console errors.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-horizontalscrollsetup-logging2-e7b9jy?file=app/app.component.ts

---

However, use the property `#` as last resort as it results in tight coupling in your application.

You may refer the below link to know more.

> https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Comment: Thank you!   I saw that on the div object and put it in but shy'd away as soon as I saw the red squiggly error from stackblitz... wierd how its coming up as an error for me in stackblitz but is working fine at runtime. Is this also happening for you?

Comment: That is because you have defined `child02` as ElementRef type, however, the inner `el` property is of type ElementRef. If you use it on `div`, then it would work as expected.

Comment: What would you suggest in order to decouple and not use # property?

Comment: The link https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef has the answer for you. If you are unable to access the DOM in any other way, then only you should use `#`.

Comment: Also, I wonder why the 'el' property is on this element... looking at past code I have never had to include this... the template reeference variable has always returned the ElementRef with the nativeElement

Comment: That is totally expected but here you are providing this tag on your custom component. In those cases, the tag must be directly on some native HTML tags such as `div`, `ul`, etc.

Comment: Okay, I see where they offer alternative solutions now.  "Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead. Alternatively you can take a look at Renderer2 which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported."  Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 5):

Update @ViewChild declaration to:

```
@ViewChild('child02',{read: ElementRef}) child02: ElementRef;
```

Keep everything else same.

[**Example**](https://angular-horizontalscrollsetup-logging2-fw8dnq.stackblitz.io)